# Bootstrap carousel sliding too far

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am building my first site with bootstrap. it is going pretty good so far.

The only problem I haven't been able to fix is:

The bootstrap carousel is sliding to far. I have 3 items in carousel each has 5 pictures.

If I press the back button repeatedly (doesn't mather how many times), the carousel cycles trough the 3 items no problem.

but if I press the next button repeatedlly, after the third times it does not reset to 0.

What could be causing this?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 thumb_box">
            <div class="thumbs">
                <div class="well">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                        <!-- Carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb1.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb1.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb1.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb1.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb1.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb1.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--/row-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb2.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb2.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb2.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb2.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb2.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb2.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--/row-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="row thumb_row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb1.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb2.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb1.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb2.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb1.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <div class="thumb">
                                            <img src="~/img/folio_thumb2.png">
                                            <a href="#" class="mask">
                                                <div class="more">+</div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--/row-->
                            </div>
                            <!--/carousel-inner-->
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--/myCarousel-->
            </div>
            <!--/well-->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
If you are having this problem check your div elements.
Something was wrong in my hierarchy of divs.